# Ordering column in specific order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT LOCATIONTYPE 
 FROM DLOCATION 
 WHERE BinCheckedOut = 'N' 
   AND submitted = 'Y' 
   AND BINNUM > 0 
   AND DISPOSED = 'N';
```

which grabs all of the `LOCATIONTYPE`'s for a display list. All of the possible `LOCATIONTYPE`'s are:

```
LOCATIONTYPE
----------------------------------------------
Forage (Represents bin 0 - 999)
International (Represents bin 1000 - 1999)
LongTermRetains (Represents bin 2000 - 2999)
Monitoring (Represents bin 3000 - 3999)
Projects (Represents bin 4000 - 4999)
RawMaterial (Represents bin 5000 - 5999)
```

However, I would like them listed in a different order by bin number. Is it possible to do this with an `order by binnum` without selecting the binnum? Is there a better way to manipulate `order by` to list them in a specific order as shown below?

```
RawMaterial
Forage  
International
LongTermRetains
Monitoring
Projects
```

Comment: what type of sql server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `GROUP BY` and a simpler `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT LOCATIONTYPE
FROM DLOCATION
WHERE BinCheckedOut = 'N' and submitted = 'Y' and
      BINNUM > 0 and DISPOSED = 'N'
GROUP BY LOCATIONTYPE
ORDER BY MIN(BINNUM);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CASE` statement to do a custom ordered list:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOCATIONTYPE FROM DLOCATION WHERE BinCheckedOut = 'N' AND
submitted = 'Y' and BINNUM > 0 and DISPOSED = 'N'
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN LOCATIONTYPE = 'rawmaterial' THEN 0 
        WHEN LOCATIONTYPE = 'Forage' THEN 1 
        WHEN LOCATIONTYPE = 'International' THEN 2 
        WHEN LOCATIONTYPE = 'LongTermRetains' THEN 3 
        WHEN LOCATIONTYPE = 'Monitoring' THEN 4 
        WHEN LOCATIONTYPE = 'Projects' THEN 5 
    END ASC
```